# Bootstrap-vue table with column span 2 by using items and fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am doing a project with using vuejs2 and bootstrap vue. I was asked to do the ui like this (just an idea of the ui):
[image]

Explanation of the part I stuck, I want to achieve a ui that have a header with column span 2 (like red part) and put 2 data under that header (like yellow part)

From the document of bootstrap vue, I know that I can hardcode the layout, but as I have to connect to the api, I wish to use (and have to use) the :item and :fields to do. Just like this:

```js
<b-table
  bordered
  responsive
  class="mt-2"
  :fields="tableFields"
  :items="tableData"
>
  <!--
    how can I do the ui in here
  -->
</b-table>
```

I would like to ask how could I achieve the ui with b-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this feature, `scoped slots` needed to be used. `:items` and `:fields` are used for simple table rendering. You need more control on the layout.

Use `b-table` along with vue directives:

```
<template>
  <b-table responsive class="mt-2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Special Header</th>
        <!-- Other headers go here -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
        <td>{{ item.field1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.field2 }}</td>
        <!-- Other cells go here -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
        // Your data goes here
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

That way, you can customize layout of table indivually and change what you need.

Hope this helps!